# Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, exception, package, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using JDK14 and IntelliJ.

```
package com.www;

public class IntroductionTo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to CSE 11");
    }
}
```

When I execute the program in terminal, it shows an error message.

[Here is the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPJMW.png)

```
jah@Weis-MacBook-Pro www % javac IntroductionTo.java
jah@Weis-MacBook-Pro www % java IntroductionTo      
Error: Could not find or load main class IntroductionTo
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/www/IntroductionTo (wrong name: IntroductionTo)
```

However if I delete the `package com.www`

```
public class IntroductionTo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to CSE 11");
    }
}
```

[Here is the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21WIo.png)

```
jah@Weis-MacBook-Pro www % javac IntroductionTo.java
jah@Weis-MacBook-Pro www % java IntroductionTo      
Welcome to CSE 11
```

It works fine.

And also, why does IntelliJ add the package for me automatically, and is it necessary to run the program?

Comment: If you have package name mentioned in your class, then open src folder in terminal, to compile type `javac com/www/IntroductionTo.java` and to run type `java com.www.IntroductionTo`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Struggle on this for several hours!